# When I sign an APK in the flavor release, the external libraries are not generated in the flavor release remain in Debug?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, build, build.gradle

The application is in the flavor release, but I have 4 libraries (modules) that when I get to generate the application those libraries are in Debug. What I want to know is how can I do so that my libraries are put in Release?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3El0O.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those 4 libraries, you should define a `release` build type in each of their build.gradle files. That will let you change their variants.

Comment: Thank you very much, but how would you configure it because I'm putting in my build.gradle :  
release {
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
}

Comment: It really is up to you to configure it since I don't know exactly what you're trying to achieve in each build variant. The question you should ask yourself is, how do you want your libraries to behave in each differing variant? What's the difference between `debug` vs `release`